# How to set appname in android java without xml modification

Tags: java, android

Without modifying android:label="@string/app_name" &  string name="app_name" in xml,can I flexibly set app name in java at OnCreate section? Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app name is a general setting, not something linked to an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible by the moment. It is a fixed string in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

If you want to change the title you may do this by this:

`getWindow().setTitle("Your Title");`

Answer (score 0):

> can I flexibly set app name in java at OnCreate section?

No , you can not , and  i believe it good thing to prevent those mess which can be produce by run-time change Application name .